# How to draw rectangle with top and bottom edge

Tags: android, canvas, rectangles

I want to draw a rectangle with only top and bottom edges but remove left and right edge of the rectangle may try below line of code but it will not be working properly how I can remove left and right edge of the rectangle.

**Actual Rectangel**

[image]

**Expected Rectangle**

[image]

**Code:**

```
canvas.clipRect(10, 0, 200, 200, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200, paint);
```

here, may remove the top edge but I don't know how to make a rectangle like expectation can anyone help me.

Comment: Why don't you just draw two lines?

Comment: I am making the glowing effect around shape so left and right edge both are expanded with device left and right edge here so I want to remove this two edge. only need to handle top and bottom edge.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#0000ff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="10dp"  android:top="10dp" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

The output is something like this:

[image]

Comment: same thing how to implement into using canvas android